# Running Kodi program makes the OS stuck

Tags: kodi

Im using ubuntu 14.04. it works fine, except for one program. I'm using Kodi program in order to watch tv using internet. sometimes it works good, sometimes it solwing my internet and sometimes it just makes my computer stuck and even when im closing the proccess it doesn't really do it. it always happen to me when i want to close the program - it stuck my computer.

i don't know if the problem is with the program or with the OS and that's what i want to ask. Is there anything i can do in order to make this program run better?

Thanks.